# How to cast between 2 types of the same name and internal sturcture but from different assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net

I got assembly 1 and assembly 2. which contain 2 types of the same name and identical internal structure.

Assembly 3 reference 1 and 2, and create a object of one of them. Now I want to cast it to the other from assembly 2.

Below is the fake code:

```
assembly1.namespace1.typeXXX obj1 = new assembly1.type1();
assembly2.namespace2.typeXXX obj2 = obj1;   <=== error here
```

How to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).
If the properties are named the same, it is as simple as this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<assembly1.type1, assembly2.type1>();
var obj2 = Mapper.Map<assembly1.type1, assembly2.type1>(obj1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use 3rd party tools.

Comment: You either use something that is already ready and working, or you invest effort and write exactly the same functionality yourself. There is no built in way.

Comment: *"Thanks, but I don't want to use 3rd party tools"*... naive

Comment: Your policy is nonsense. .NET is third party. Your two objects are third party as you said in one comment. I guess, you just have to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Without meaning to sound condescending... if that's the policy which is being forced on you, I would recommend that you push back very hard, as the people making this policy clearly have no programming expertise...

Answer (score 0):

This two types are different because of they are in different assemblies, you will have to copy Property to Property.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* define [custom casting operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx), but I think in this case that would only add confusion. My question is, why have you defined two identical (but separate) classes? Why not just use one of them?

Another alternative is to map between the types. If you don't have control over their source code, you could do this with an extension method:

```
public static class TypeOneExtensions
{ 
    public static TypeTwo AsTypeTwo(this TypeOne typeOne)
    {
        return new TypeTwo
        {
            PropertyA = typeOne.PropertyA,
            PropertyB = typeOne.PropertyB,
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Note though that this creates a new instance of `TypeTwo`, so changes you make to it won't be reflected in the original `TypeOne` instance.

Comment: the 2 types are from 3rd party, i have no control to them.

Comment: In that case I would go with @Daniel Hilgarth's suggestion and use AutoMapper or a custom mapping method (perhaps as an extension method).

Answer (score 0):

I got one dirty solution:

Use XML serialize the obj1, hack into the XML and replace "namespace1" with "namespace2". And then deserialize the XML into obj2.

Comment: Ouch... Performance considerations etc? Using this just because you don't want to use 3rd party tools is nonsense...

Answer (score 0):

The same question happens to me.

This code maybe can help you!

```
using type1=assembly1.namespace1.typeXXX;
using type2=assembly2.namespace2.typeXXX;
```

Or, You can read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx)

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't work in his case, because the full qualified name of the types is different (namespace1 <-> namespace2)